# ComboBox.FindStringExact(string s) - what use is it to return 0 if string s is Empty?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I am very curious about this tidbit in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c440x2eb(v=vs.100).aspx) for this method:

> Return Value
>   Type: System.Int32
>   The zero-based index of the first item found; returns -1 if no match is found, **or 0 if the s parameter specifies Empty.**

I simply cannot fathom of what use is it to someone to have this method return 0 if the supplied string is Empty. Remember that the return is supposed to be a zero-based index of the position of the matched string in the combobox. So when you get a return of 0, with this method, it can either be that the string you searched for was in position 0, or that the string you searched for was Empty. The same result for two very different situations.

And what happens if you are specifically searching for an Empty string, which happens to be in position, say, 5? This method would then return 0, no?

I just want to understand what is the intention of this little caveat, and how to use it properly.

Comment: In real, it doesn't return 0, for empty string, if there is an item with empty string it will return its index, otherwise it will return `-1`, so I believe there is a flaw in the documentation.

Comment: I wonder if the documentation got switched between ComboBox.FindString and ComboBox.FindStringExact. The documentation for FindString does not include this phrase, but it would make sense in that case.

Comment: @Dave: That's it! FindString returns 0 for an empty search string, no matter if ther is an empty item or not. FindStringExact returns the index or -1. Do they hand out prizes for that kind of find?

Comment: Probably 10 Bing Rewards Points

Comment: MSDN updated with Community Addition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation error: The phrase "or 0 if the s parameter specifies Empty" should be part of the documentation for ComboBox.GetString, NOT ComboBox.GetStringExact